# How could penetration between human models be avoided?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

In a fight scene I have several actions where the movement is only limted by the freedom of movement of the rigged bones. When a punch hits the body of the other character it shouldn't penetrate the body hit it should rather push it away or stop when the collision is detected.

[image]

Can this be achieved with rigid body constraints?

The two characters are linked into the scene and have proxies, 
I tried several settings in this dialog but whatever I do it seems to have no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Blender isn't capable of doing that (yet). I've tried combining armature-based animation with physics-based cloth/rigid body simulation, and the latter always override any manual animation I've made.

I'd try to limit the range of punch based on bounding-box proximity between the two characters, or trigger a knocked-back animation (faster than the punch animation) depending on how far the punch animation is played + bounding-box proximity.

Comment: Thanks, could you please add a reference on how bounding-box proximity is setup? Or is there another name for it I couldn't find any resources on that topic.

Comment: That'd require some Python BGE coding, which I have next to no experience in. I've used [`bound_box`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.bound_box) for similar purpose, but strictly for F-curve based animation. Sorry.